# Combinations including if statement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can a committee of 3 woman and 4 girls be chosen from 7 women and 6 girls such that if the eldest woman is in the committee then the youngest girl is not.
I'm just not sure how the last bit factors in to the calculation.

Comment: Just work the cases separately.  Suppose first that the eldest woman is not on the committee.  Then suppose that she is.  Add the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two distinct cases.

1) The eldest woman **is** on the committee. Then it remains to choose $3-1$ women out of $7-1$ and $4$ girls out of $6-1$ (minus the youngest girl).

2) The eldest woman **is not**  on the committee. Then we have to choose $3$ women out of $7-1$ (minus the eldest woman) and $4$ girls out of $6$.